# Tar command in Python scripting fails after adding two variables

Tags: python-3.x, linux, centos7

I'm facing an error while slightly changing the last step of my Python script, could anyone help me out?

**1- Asking for input**

```
vm = 'input your VM name'

#centos
```

**2- Defining a path manually**

```
path = 'var/lib/libvirt/images/centos.qcow2' 
#Directory of centos image file
```

**3- get the date**

```
var=os.popen('date +"%Y%m%d"')
vmdate=var.read()
#20220622
```

**4- Create a Tar archive file that contains two files.**

```
os.system('tar cvJf ' + vm + '.tar.xz ' + vm + '.xml' + ' ' + path)

#create a Tar archive file that contains the centos.xml file and centos.qcow2 file. This command works fine and the output is: centos.tar.xz
```

**BUT**

**5-When I tried to add the date after the name of Tar archive (20220622) I got the below error.** (I want to change the Tar file name to centos20220622.tar.xz (vm+vmdate.tar.xz))

```
os.system('tar cvJf ' + vm + vmdate + '.tar.xz ' + vm + '.xml' + ' ' + path)
```

**Error Message:**

```
tar: Cowardly refusing to create an empty archive
Try `tar --help' or `tar --usage' for more information.
sh: line 1: /home/aku/bin/.tar.xz: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first add the forward slash..

```
path = '/var/lib/libvirt/images/centos.qcow2'
```

and strip the \n in your date, it will work...

```
>>> vmdate
'20220622\n'

>>> vmdate.rstrip()
'20220622'
```